# django-user-accounts doesn't throw any error?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I am using pinax/django-user-accounts for my user authentication in django. The problem is that I never get an error shown in my template when I enter wrong details.

According to this : [pinax/forms.py](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/blob/master/account/forms.py) , shouldn't I be getting the error messages ?
Isn't clean_email? supposed to throw an error if we enter a duplicate email ?

The password validation in `clean()` works fine though. So I tried putting the `clean_email()` logic in `clean`, even that doesn't work.

I am not able to find the  mistake if I am doing any.

Thanks

Comment: Is the issue regarding errors not being shown in template or errors not being thrown at all? 
Can you check the value of `form.errors` in the view before rendering template.

Comment: form does throw errors. When I remove the as_bootstrap tag I get the field specific error.

Comment: Which library have you used for bootstrap? You may check its documentation for displaying errors.

Comment: I have raised an issue, thanks